# How to use global intercept for all tests in Cypress 6?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, cypress

I want to test every page of my site (Vue/Nuxt), but API calls should be mocked.

For that there is intercept() function (route() in previous Cypress versions):

homepage.spec.js:

```
describe('home page', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.intercept('**/user-data', { fixture: 'user.json' })
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8080')
  })

  it('renders header, () => {
      cy.contains('#header', 'test');
  });

  // some other tests for homepage
});
```

Cool, it works, but I have this specific API call (getting logged user info) on every page. I don't want to repeat this intercept code in every test file, for example contact.spec.js. I cannot find a way to set this intercept globally? What is the correct way to mocking axios?

Comment: *but all API calls should be mocked* so are all api calls the same? if not it would make sense that you do indeed mock only the endpoint needed for the test, imo adding one line `cy.intercept(..., {...})` is not too much of a workload

Comment: No, what I mean was that I will be mocking all API calls. But this particular one (/user-data) is present on every single page, so it just feels wrong to repeat exact same intercept code on every single test.

Comment: Imo it would be fine to have in each test, you could also abstract it into a [command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax) so you're just running one line `cy.userDataMock()` etc and you could if you want it global, just listen to a call to `test:before:run` and run the command https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Binding-to-Events

Comment: thanks i will check that

Comment: listening to `test:before:run` doesn't work, because `Cannot call 'cy.intercept()' outside a running test`

Answer (score 5):

There's no 'global intercept' in cypress but you can add a `beforeEach` hook to a support file that will apply to every test case:

`cypress/support/e2e.ts`

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept()
})
```